# Segmentation fault when running lvcreate

Tags: lvm, buildroot

I'm trying to use a minimal buildroot based linux system live cd, and I need to do some partitioning, preferably using LVM. But LVM doesn't seem to work. I get segmenetation fault when running `lvcreate`... But the volume seems to be created anyway. I can't create it again, but it does not get mapped in `/dev`. Is there some specific package that I need to enable, or is this some bug?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved it by changing libc to glibc instead of uclibc. I also enabled `DM uevents` in the kernel.